# How to convert an array of bytes to a hex string?

Tags: php, arrays, converters

I have a solution, but this solution is slow.
Example:

```
$arr = array(14, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 224, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255);
$hex_str = "";
foreach ($arr as $byte)
{
    $hex_str .= sprintf("%02X", $byte);
}
```

Result is: 0E0001000000000000E000FFFFFFFFFF

Format is:

```
255 => FF
0 => 00
1 => 01
14 => 0E
```

If you know a faster solution, share it please.

Comment: You code works and is trivial. There is no way to accomplish what you need in a way that will ever save you more time than you've already spent typing out the question.

Answer (score 11):

You could cast each integer to an char first.

```
$chars = array_map("chr", $arr);
```

Then make it a string:

```
$bin = join($chars);
```

And finally convert that to a hex string:

```
$hex = bin2hex($bin);
```

See: [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map), [`chr`](http://php.net/chr), [`join`](http://php.net/join), [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/bin2hex). (And of course you could do it all in one line.)

Comment: Nice step by step solution with references :) ! (Not too sure if OP really wants the letters in uppercase, if yes OP just would have to use `strtoupper`)

Comment: I also doubt that it's "faster" in any way. (Just faster to read perhaps.)

Comment: yep, I'm also not really sure, what exactly OP is looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211772/how-to-convert-an-array-of-bytes-to-a-hex-string/31211886?noredirect=1#comment50425505_31211772 with his question.

Comment: I guess it's just one of those micro-optimization questions.